# Launching WPF app from UnitTest on TFS starts process but does not launch app

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, tfs

I am trying to Launch a WPF App from within a unit test in order for that unit test to carry out tests on the UI.

Executing the test on my local environment works as expected - App is launched, tests are carried out and App is closed. Executing the tests through a TFS build however, seems to do something strange. The Solution builds successfully and tests start but the App never launches. There is a Process running for the App but the UI never makes an appearance.

The server environment is Windows Server 2012 and TFS 2013. The App process runs as a Background Process rather than an App.

Can anyone provide any insight to why my App is not launching properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build agent needs to be running in Interactive mode.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx

However, I would recommend against doing UI testing on a build agent. This will drastically slow your build and it will no longer be a quick CI. You should instead use Release Management to deploy your application to a client and execute the tests through that. If you use MS Test as the orchestrator (use Selenium, CUIT, or whatever as the engine) you can associate the test and the results with a Test Case. This gives you some pretty cool reporting capabilities as you can now see UI coverage against builds...

http://nakedalm.com/execute-tests-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am pretty sure you are right with the Interactive Mode suggestion. I will confirm tomorrow. I am currently in a proving phase for this so what you have suggested will probably be the solution we arrive at. Thanks again for your answer.